# Blazor component inheritance: Derived component HTML inside parent's html

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to create a BaseComponent with shared logic and template. For that I created this "base class" inside of `MyBaseComponent.razor`:

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <!-- Derived Content is expected here -->
</div>
<button onclick="@ButtonClick" disabled=@(!IsEnabled)>Click me</button>

@code{
  public virtual void ButtonClick() {
     // do nothing in base class
  }

  public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to implement multiple derived classes, e.g. `MyDerivedComponentA.razor`

```
@inherits MyBaseComponent

<p>Template inside of MyDerivedComponentA!</p>
<button onclick="@ActivateParentButton">Activate parent button</button>

@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code{
  public override void ButtonClick() {
     // Do something in derived class
  }

  public void ActivateParentButton(){
     IsEnabled = true;
  }
}
```

This works with one exception: The template of the parent component will be rendered after the derived component's layout. I tried to use some `RenderFragment`s like `ChildContent` and `Body` but to no avail.

Is there anything I'm missing? Otherwise, is there any other way to solve this specific use case of shared logic and templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way you can achieve this.

Use a RenderFragment for the derived content in the base markup:

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  @DerivedContent
</div>
<button onclick="@ButtonClick" disabled=@(!IsEnabled)>Click me</button>

@code{
  protected RenderFragment DerivedContent {get;set;} 

  public virtual void ButtonClick() {
     // do nothing in base class
  }

  public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then set the DerivedContent in your derived component:

```html
@inherits MyBase
@{
    DerivedContent = @<text>
<p>Template inside of MyDerivedComponentA!</p>
<button onclick="@ActivateParentButton">Activate parent button</button>
</text>;
}
@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code{
  public override void ButtonClick() {
     // Do something in derived class
  }

  public void ActivateParentButton(){
     IsEnabled = true;
  }
}
```

And call the base BuildRenderTree as before.

[Here's a demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cmYVlcvY54U0KeJg21)

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by MisterMagoo does the job, but it's a bit ugly and messy.  It's impossible to implement a more elegant solution with `ComponentBase` as you don't have access to the internal private render state fields.  You can't create and pass an alternative render fragment to the Renderer.

Here's the solution I currently use:

Create a new base component based on `ComponentBase` with the fields we need access to changed from `private` to `protected`.

Here's the code:

```cs
public abstract class TemplateComponentBase : IComponent, IHandleEvent, IHandleAfterRender
{
    protected RenderFragment _renderFragment;
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    protected bool _initialized;
    protected bool _hasNeverRendered = true;
    protected bool _hasPendingQueuedRender;
    protected bool _hasCalledOnAfterRender;

    public TemplateComponentBase()
    {
        _renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
            _hasNeverRendered = false;
            BuildRenderTree(builder);
        };
    }

    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) {}
    protected virtual void OnInitialized() {}
    protected virtual Task OnInitializedAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
    protected virtual void OnParametersSet() { }
    protected virtual Task OnParametersSetAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;
    protected virtual bool ShouldRender() => true;
    protected virtual void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) { }
    protected virtual Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) => Task.CompletedTask;
    protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem) => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);
    protected Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> workItem) => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);

    protected void StateHasChanged()
    {
        if (_hasPendingQueuedRender)
            return;

        if (_hasNeverRendered || ShouldRender() || _renderHandle.IsRenderingOnMetadataUpdate)
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = true;

            try
            {
                _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);
            }
            catch
            {
                _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    void IComponent.Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
    {
        if (_renderHandle.IsInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The render handle is already set. Cannot initialize a {nameof(ComponentBase)} more than once.");

        _renderHandle = renderHandle;
    }

    public virtual Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        if (!_initialized)
        {
            _initialized = true;

            return this.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync();
        }
        else
            return this.CallOnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private async Task RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
    {
        this.OnInitialized();

        var task = this.OnInitializedAsync();

        if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();

            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
            {
                if (!task.IsCanceled)
                    throw;
            }
        }

        await this.CallOnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private Task CallOnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        this.OnParametersSet();

        var task = this.OnParametersSetAsync();
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            this.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch 
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                return;

            throw;
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            this.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        var firstRender = !_hasCalledOnAfterRender;
        _hasCalledOnAfterRender |= true;

        OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        return this.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

Used as-is it's has exactly the same functionality as `ComponentBase`.

You can now create a template component and override the new method.  You now have access to the render controlling fields.

**MyTemplate**

```
@inherits TemplateComponentBase

<div class="@this.mainCss">
    <div class="h4">Page Template</div>
    @Childcontent
    <div>
        This content is within the template page below the child content
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" @onclick=ChangeSet>Change colour</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```cs
public abstract partial class MyTemnplate : TemplateComponentBase
{
    private bool aglow = true;
    protected virtual RenderFragment? Childcontent => (builder) => this.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    protected abstract RenderFragment BaseContent { get; }

    public MyTemplate()
    {
        _renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
            _hasNeverRendered = false;
            builder.AddContent(0, BaseContent);
        };
    }

    private string mainCss => aglow
        ? "p-2 bg-secondary text-white"
        : "p-2 bg-primary text-white";

    private void ChangeSet()
        => aglow = !aglow;
}
```

And then use the temnplate in the index page:

**Index**

```
@page "/"
@inherits MyTemplate

<div class="@this.css">
    <div class="h2">Hello Blazor</div>
    <div>
        This content is within the child content page
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" @onclick=ChangeSet>Change colour</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override RenderFragment BaseContent => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

    private string css => alight
        ? "bg-light text-primary p-2 m-2"
        : "bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2";

    private bool alight = true;

    private void ChangeSet()
        => alight = !alight;
}
```

The only thing you must implement is:

```cs
    protected override RenderFragment BaseContent => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
```

To set the correct base content.  I haven't figured out how to do this automatically.

I've added a couple of UI events to  make it interactive and show that the re-rendering happens correctly.

Comment: Nice solution but for future Googlers, this solution doesn't work with generic classes:

public abstract partial class MyTemplate<T> : TemplateComponentBase
{
public MyTemplate() {
   _renderFragment = ...

CSO103: The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context